# How to export react-bootstrap table in to pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, react-bootstrap-table

I have a react-bootstrap table and I need to export table data to a pdf. 'useReactToPrint' along with useRef is not working properly. Any other method campatible with react-bootstrap table?

Generate a pdf including react-bootstrap table data

Comment: I was able to solve my problem through jspdf-autotable & jspdf. 
.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.